# ssh to ubuntu system works but putty to same system does not

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a Ubuntu linux box. Putty to it used to work. after upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10 I can no longer use putty to access the system. When I try to access it with Putty it just hangs. But if I access it with ssh from another linux box it works. I have tried disabling the firewall, but that did not help.

Any suggestions what to try next??

Dennis

```
pUTTY Log:
2016-03-10 16:20:36 Looking up host "192.168.1.99" 
2016-03-10 16:20:36 Connecting to 192.168.1.99 port 22 
2016-03-10 16:20:36 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1 
2016-03-10 16:20:36 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Local:_Nov_25_2007_00:07:33 
2016-03-10 16:20:36 Using SSH protocol version 2 
2016-03-10 16:20:36 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
```

Comment: Check server's `auth.log` while connecting from putty to see what's going on.

Comment: No entry shows up in auth.log at all

Comment: Then the problem may be in the putty or in the pc you are trying from. See if you can ping the server and telnet to ssh port.

Comment: I have tried putty from 2 different systems and I have the same issue from both systems. And I can putty to another linux box.

Comment: Well, first of all you need to understand that, putty is just a ssh client, so pls make sure you can reach server's ssh port from the pc's you are talking about. You can check that with doing telnet on ssh port and checking server logs. Also if you have misconfiguration (wrong hostname/port) in putty, then it also wont work for sure from any machine you try.

Comment: That is why it baffles me so much. Winscp from the windows systems I am trying putty from works as does ssh from a linux box. Just not Putty.

Comment: The putty log shows it does not make it through key exchange:
2016-03-10 16:20:36 Looking up host "192.168.1.99"
2016-03-10 16:20:36 Connecting to 192.168.1.99 port 22
2016-03-10 16:20:36 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1
2016-03-10 16:20:36 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Local:_Nov_25_2007_00:07:33
2016-03-10 16:20:36 Using SSH protocol version 2
2016-03-10 16:20:36 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange

Comment: Can you post the full log in your original post?

Comment: Could it be that putty insists on DSA, which is disabled in new Ubuntu?

Comment: Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: @DennisKerrisk, the logs you have posted, well there is no error or anything. I'm sure you are missing something. But well, here is one last thing I would like to add, just create a new key, and/or setup putty again, and see if it works.

Comment: No that is where it stops, nothing more. It is looking like the previous response might be the issue, so I am looking into it now.

Comment: Make sure you use the latest release of PuTTY.

Comment: Your symptoms sound a bit like a PMTU problem. Except if that was the case I'd expect it to affect all clients. It's also not a very likely to happen on a LAN. Still, it would be interesting to see a capture of the network traffic to know for certain if there is an issue at the TCP layer. (Btw. are you related to Michael Kerrisk?)

Comment: @MichaelHampton especially since that outgoing version string looks like a snapshot not an official release. Also if you have the full package, try console-mode `[\path\to\]plink -v user@host echo test` -- it *probably* will be the same as putty, but it's worth a quick shot.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Not sure what's worst. Running a snapshot release. Or running a version that hasn't been updated for years. An update to a newer version is 8 years overdue.